# How would you search a single column in a CSV dict, then access another column in the same row?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have read the following csv file into a CSV dictionary in python:

```
name,password
alice,123456
carol,654321
```

I created the CSV dictionary using the following code:

```
with open('users.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
```

I would like to find the  **password** associated with a given **name**.

**3 Solutions Found:**

It turns out to be easier to manage csv data using a pandas dataframe.

```
searchName = "bob"
searchPassword = None

df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv')    # read csv file into pandas DF

# Method 1
for name, password in zip(df["name"], df["password"]):
    if (name == searchName):
        searchPassword = password
        break

# Method 2
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # row is indexed like a list, where 0 is the 0th column or the name
    if row[0] == searchName:
        searchPassword = df.loc[index, "password"]
        break

# Method 3  -- oneliner
try:
    searchPassword = df[df["name"] == searchName].iloc[0]["password"]
except:
    pass # not searchName and corresponding searchPassword not found

# -- now do some routine based on whether name&password were found
if (searchPassword != None):
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

Comment: What does CVS dictionary mean? Can you represent it as a python code?

Comment: "that would require iterating over the elements of the 1st column until a match is found" - sure, that's one of the possible approaches! So, you solved the problem yourself right in your post?

Comment: I'm looking for a shortcut way to do it, instead of coding my own for loop

Comment: I mean, csv.DictReader just gives a dict right? So why not just do if my_val in csv_reader

Comment: Just use `pandas` - and mentioned by @CatalinaChircu below.

Comment: What's a CSV dictionary, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what you mean by a CSV dictionary. If you mean a CSV file, you may use `pandas` `DataFrame`. In this case you will read the whole file and set it in a variable, then search in it.

```
import csv 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=inFile, low_memory=False, encoding='utf-8', sep=sep)
name_to_search = 'alice'
password = df.loc[:,'name']=name_to_search
```